# Como traduzir a query de MySql que tenha uma soma para Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Preciso traduzir a seguinte query de MySql para Hibernate:

```
select sum(TOTAL_MERCADORIA_BRL) from PROCESSO group by PERIODO like 'DEZ-15';
```

Qual seria a melhor maneira de se fazer essa query, porém utilizando Hibernate?

Comment: O Hibernate pode executar SQL nativo ou é um requisito transformar em HQL(Hibernate Query Language)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Hibernate pode executar SQL Nativo.

Segue um exemplo:

```
String sql = "select sum(TOTAL_MERCADORIA_BRL) from PROCESSO group by PERIODO like 'DEZ-15'";
SQLQuery query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
BigDecimal result = query.uniqueResult();
```

Agora o mesmo exemplo usando HQL(Hibernate Query Language).

```
String hql= "select sum(bean.totalMercadoria) from Processo bean where bean.periodo = 'DEZ-15' group by bean.periodo";
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
BigDecimal result = query.uniqueResult();
```

`Processo` na HQL é o nome da Entidade mapeada e o `bean` é o aliás que criei, mas você pode colocar o nome que você quiser. O `bean.periodo` faz referência ao nome do atributo da entidade mapeada, levei em consideração que o `PERIODO` é do tipo varchar agora se for do tipo Date você pode fazer desta forma

```
Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select sum(bean.totalMercadoria) from Processo bean where bean.periodo = :data group by bean");
q.setParameter("data", variavelData, TemporalType.DATE);
```

O objeto `sessionFactory` é do tipo [SessionFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html).

Comment: Entendi, não sabia que eu poderia usar o SQL nativo!

Answer (score 1):

É utilizando HQL caso estiver apenas com Hibernate, e JPQL caso estiver com JPA implementando com qualquer outra ferramenta como Hibernate, Eclipse Link e OpenJPA.

```
SELECT SUM(p.totalMercadoriaBrl) FROM Processo p WHERE p.periodo LIKE :periodo GROUP BY p.periodo
```

A referencia `:periodo` é para o parametro que estiver passando

O Processo é equivalente a *classe* `Processo`, e seus atributos `periodo` e `totalMercadoriaBrl`

- Segue a documentação comparando JPQL com HQL

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html

- Documentação referente a JPQL

https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html